# BoxLayout в Java или GUIёвый вопрос

Tags: gui, java

Пытаюсь получить табличку из кнопок в центре фрейма, но они растягиваюстся на всё окно. Видно, диспетчер компоновки игнорирует метод setPreferredSize(). Может, у кого-то есть ответ, как это можно исправить.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class GridTest
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelB = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panelB.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3,3);
    panelB.setLayout(grid);

    Icon[] icon = new Icon[24];

    icon[0] = new ImageIcon("Img/Item/ArmletMordiggian.gif");
    icon[1]= new ImageIcon("Img/Item/AssaultCuirass.gif");
    icon[2] = new ImageIcon("Img/Item/Mekansm.gif");
    icon[3] = new ImageIcon("Img/Item/Bloodstone.gif");
    icon[4] = new ImageIcon("Img/Item/Butterfly.gif");

    icon[5] = new ImageIcon("Img/Item/Chainmail.gif");
    icon[6] = new ImageIcon("Img/Item/Eaglehorn.gif");
    icon[7] = new ImageIcon("Img/Item/EnergyBooster.gif");
    icon[8] = new ImageIcon("Img/Item/GlovesHaste.gif");

    JButton[]button = new JButton[9];

    for (int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
     button[i] = new JButton(icon[i]);
     button[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(32,32));
     panelB.add(button[i]);
    }
     panel.add(panelB);
     frame.add(panel);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setResizable(false);
     frame.setSize(500,500);
     frame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

Comment: Swing сам по себе не очень логичен, многие свойства иногда используются, а иногда и игнорируются. Сочувствую.

Comment: Да не, какое то должно быть этому объяснение)Подождём, может найдутся шарящие в этом люди.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал диспетчер компоновки `GridBagLayout`. Он учитывает желательные размеры компонента.